# Missing `fastcgi_cache_purge` from Centos 7 EPEL `yum install nginx`

Tags: nginx, centos, centos7, epel

I installed nginx on Centos 7.1 with `yum install nginx` (from the EPEL repos). I am setting up WordPress caching as per https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx and getting `unknown directive "fastcgi_cache_purge"` error on start.

I dont have the module `fastcgi_cache_purge` compiled in, is there any default build from a repo that I can use or do I need to recompile my own?

```
[root@www1 ~]# nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.6.3
built by gcc 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC)
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments:
--prefix=/usr/share/nginx
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi
--pid-path=/run/nginx.pid
--lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx
--user=nginx --group=nginx
--with-file-aio
--with-ipv6
--with-http_ssl_module
--with-http_spdy_module
--with-http_realip_module
--with-http_addition_module
--with-http_xslt_module
--with-http_image_filter_module
--with-http_geoip_module
--with-http_sub_module
--with-http_dav_module
--with-http_flv_module
--with-http_mp4_module
--with-http_gunzip_module
--with-http_gzip_static_module
--with-http_random_index_module
--with-http_secure_link_module
--with-http_degradation_module
--with-http_stub_status_module
--with-http_perl_module
--with-mail
--with-mail_ssl_module
--with-pcre
--with-pcre-jit
--with-google_perftools_module
--with-debug
--with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic'
--with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-ld -Wl,-E'
```

Comment: Nope. “This functionality is available as part of our commercial subscription.”

Comment: I use Wordfence Falcon Nginx caching with the free Nginx Repo install of CentOS7. Works perfectly and all the setup is done for / presented to you. It handles the purging for you too.